# Don't get into me!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I'm not hot if you're in me,
I can be hot if I'm in you.

You live like dogs if you're in me
And pant like dogs if I'm in you.

Kids steal cookies: they're in me;
Kids make coffee: I'm in you.

*Who am I?*

Comment: Whoa, so dirty!  — oh, nevermind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> **hot water**?

I'm not hot if you're in me,
I can be hot if I'm in you.

> If you're in "hot water" you're not literally in something hot.
>  If hot water is in you, say you've drunk some (in coffee or tea), it can be hot.

You live like dogs if you're in me
And pant like dogs if I'm in you.

> If you're in hot water, you're in the dog house.
>  If hot water is in you, you may pant from the heat?

Kids steal cookies: they're in me;
Kids make coffee: I'm in you.

> Kids stealing cookies will land them in hot water.
>  Kids making coffee, and letting you drink some, will put hot water in you.

Comment: Not bad, you've got it!

Comment: No mention of [___pants](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hot_pants)?